# Maps from a topology to a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,\mathcal{T}_X)$ and $(Y,\mathcal{T}_Y)$ be topological spaces. Is there a notion of a map $f:\mathcal{T}_1\to\mathcal{T}_2$?

Some motivation: first, I'm mainly wondering if there are sufficient conditions to show that two spaces are homeomorphic given the existence of a particular $f:\mathcal{T}_1\to\mathcal{T}_2$. For homeomorphic spaces $X,Y$, the map being invertible is likely a necessary condition. My naive guess is that another necessary condition is that open sets of some cardinality are mapped (in bijection) to open sets of the same cardinality, although this is difficult to describe for infinite sets.

Second, for a measure space $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ with $\mu:\mathcal{M}\to\overline{\mathbb{R}}$, I could think of $\mu$ as $\mu':\mathcal{M}\to\mathscr{P}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$, where $x\mapsto[0,x]\in\mathscr{P}(\overline{\mathbb{R}})$. In other words, this map $f$ could allow me to think of set functions $\mu$ as a certain type of this map.

I have a small suspicion that my question may be closer to category theory than topology, but I'm not familiar with categories. If this is the case, then could I know what construction this is?

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, there certainly is such a notion, which you may well know. Any homeomorphism $f : X \mapsto Y$ induces a partial order preserving bijection $\mathcal T_X \mapsto \mathcal T_Y$ given by $U \mapsto f(U)$. More generally, any continuous function $g : Y \to X$ induces a partial order preserving function (not generally a bijection) $\mathcal T_X \to \mathcal T_Y$ given by $U \mapsto g^{-1}(U)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_group This may be relevant, although I don't see how to make a group out of the homeomorphisms $X\to Y$.

Comment: Note that if both $\mathcal{T}_1$ and $\mathcal{T}_2$ are antidiscrete (meaning of cardinality $2$) then no map $\mathcal{T}_1\to\mathcal{T}_2$ will tell us much. And requiring such map to preserve cardinality will easily lead to reconstructing a homomorphism. Meaning I don't see much sense in such notion.